# How to add filename to drawtext in video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to display the file name in the video with drawtext .
For example, I have a file list :
C:\Users\ffmpeg code\1.mp4
C:\Users\ffmpeg code\2.mp4
...

I want 1.mp4 add text "1" into video, 2.mp4 add text "2" into video, similar to other videos.

I tried :
ffmpeg  -i "{input}.*"  -vf drawtext="fontfile=C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:fontsize=20: fontcolor=red:x=10:y=10:text=?filename?" -preset ultrafast "{output}.mp4" .

It's hard to name each file into the drawtext section